# TSQL: Why not running?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    Tbl_RecibosCobroComisionesDetalle.MontoComision, 
    Tbl_Recibos.IdRecibo, Tbl_RecibosCobros.IdCobro
FROM 
    Tbl_RecibosCobroComisionesDetalle 
INNER JOIN  
    Tbl_RecibosCobroComisiones ON Tbl_RecibosCobroComisionesDetalle.IdCobroComision = Tbl_RecibosCobroComisiones.IdCobroComision 
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Recibos 
INNER JOIN   
    Tbl_Polizas ON Tbl_Polizas.IdPoliza = Tbl_Recibos.IdPoliza 
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_Ramos ON Tbl_Polizas.IdRamo = Tbl_Ramos.IdRamo 
INNER JOIN  
    Tbl_Empresas ON Tbl_Recibos.IdEmpresa = Tbl_Empresas.IdEmpresa 
INNER JOIN  
    Tbl_RecibosCobrosDetalle ON Tbl_Recibos.IdRecibo = Tbl_RecibosCobrosDetalle.IdRecibo 
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_RecibosCobros ON Tbl_RecibosCobrosDetalle.IdCobro = Tbl_RecibosCobros.IdCobro 
INNER JOIN
    Tbl_CompaniasSeguro  ON Tbl_CompaniasSeguro.IdCompania = Tbl_Polizas.IdCompania 
WHERE 
    (Tbl_Recibos.IdEstatus = 6) 
    AND Tbl_Empresas.IdEmpresa = @IdEmpresa
    AND Tbl_Recibos.FechaCancelado >= @fDE 
    AND Tbl_Recibos.FechaCancelado <= @fHasta 
    AND Tbl_RecibosCobros.IdEstatus = 1 
    AND Tbl_Recibos.Comision < 0
```

SQL Server returns this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

After Inner Join "`Tbl_CompaniasSeguro  ON Tbl_CompaniasSeguro.IdCompania = Tbl_Polizas.IdCompania`"

Say: "`AN EXPRESSION OF NON-BOOLEAN TYPE SPECIFIED IN A CONTEXT WHERE CONDITION IS EXPECTED`"

Why is that?

Comment: you are missing the join condition for `Tbl_Recibos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an `ON` in this section:

```
INNER JOIN     
    Tbl_RecibosCobroComisiones.IdCobroComision ON Tbl_RecibosCobroComisionesDetalle.IdCobroComision = Tbl_RecibosCobroComisiones.IdCobroComision  
INNER JOIN 
    Tbl_Recibos 
INNER JOIN 
   ......
```

Comment: Thanks @marc_s that's much more cleanly formatted :-)